# Values selected in select box cannot be retrieved- jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an application in which I have table with form elements like select, input etc.  I want to populate the values selected in form elements to another table.

You can find my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/archanabr05/wrpw51v0/1/)

JS:

```
 $('button').click(function() {
  var rows = $('#table1 tbody tr');
  var previewTable = $('#table2 tbody');
  previewTable.find('tr').remove();
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   var tr = $('<tr> </tr>');
   previewTable.append(tr);
   var row_cloned = $(rows[i]).clone();
   var cols = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
   for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
    var col_cloned = row_cloned.find('td').clone();
    previewTable.find('tr').eq(i).append(col_cloned[j]);


    if ($(col_cloned[j]).children().length > 0) {
     $(col_cloned[j]).children().each(function(index, item) {
      if ($(item).is('select')) {
        if ($(item).attr('multiple')) {
          var foo = [];
          $(item).each(function(i, selected) {
            console.log($(selected).val());
            foo[i] = $(selected).val();
          });
          $(col_cloned[j]).text(foo);
        } else {
          $(col_cloned[j]).text($(item).val());
        }

      } else if ($(item).is('label')) {
        var selected = [];
        $(item).find('input:checked').each(function(index, item) {
          selected.push($(item).val());
          $(col_cloned[j]).append(selected + '<br>');
        })
      }
    })
  } else {
    $(col_cloned[j]).text($(col_cloned[j]).text());
    }
   }
  }
})
```

My steps:

1. Get table1 and table2
2. Count the number of rows in the table1
3. Add so many empty rows in the table2
4. Get each row in table1
5. Count the td in each row of table1
6. Find the children in each td
7. Check if children is select, input, or just plain text
8. If children is select, determine if it is multi-select or single
9. Act accordingly for each form elements to copy only values and then append to table2
10. finish

All this on a button click COPY

Problem: Somehow managed to get the checked input form element values. But failing to get the values selected in select box.

For multi select box my code:

```
if ($(item).attr('multiple')) {
      var foo = [];
      $(item).each(function(i, selected) {
        console.log($(selected).val());
        foo[i] = $(selected).val();
      });
      $(col_cloned[j]).text(foo);
    }
```

For single select box :

```
else {
      $(col_cloned[j]).text($(item).val());
    }
```

What is my mistake exactly? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, Are cell input types fixed ? I mean for example select will be always to the 1st cell ?

Comment: Yes, cell form fields are fixed.

Comment: @Legionar: The link your pointing to is a total different scenario. And as well, I have tried the possible solutions provided there.

Comment: Check the code in my answer, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

For selected `.val()` does not work.You will have to use `find()` as in reality when you select a select box , its value does not change.

```
 if ($(item).attr('multiple')) {
     var foo = [];
     $(item).each(function(i, selected) {
     foo[i] = $(selected).find(":selected").text();  // see this
     });
     $(col_cloned[j]).text(foo);
  } else {
     $(col_cloned[j]).text($(item).find(":selected").text());  // see this
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For `<select>` you can't use `val()`.

Using the `.val()` function on a multi-select list will return an array of the selected values:

This code:

```
if ($(item).is('select')) {
    if ($(item).attr('multiple')) {
      var foo = [];
      $(item).each(function(i, selected) {
        console.log($(selected).val());
        foo[i] = $(selected).val();
      });
      $(col_cloned[j]).text(foo);
    } else {
      $(col_cloned[j]).text($(item).val());
    }

  }
```

Change to this:

```
if ($(item).is('select')) {
    if ($(item).attr('multiple')) {
      var foo = $('#multipleSelect').val();
      $(col_cloned[j]).text(foo);
    } else {
      var optionSelected = $(item).find("option:selected");
      $(col_cloned[j]).text(optionSelected.val());
    }

  }
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Explain "this not work"! It must give any error or warning... You have debug it in browser Console

Comment: The value is taking as null for multi select box and for single select, it is taking the first option. No error or no warnings

Comment: See my edit. Is it ok now? `$(col_cloned[j]).text(foo);` this will change text to list of objects in array... Are you sure, you need it so?

Comment: This is not working, for single select, still the first option and for multi select, it is copying the whole select box to table2.